# Using DELETE FROM with LEAD function

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, lead

Using SQL Server 2014, I have a table that keeps track of cash register sales. If the register operator scans an item in error, it will create two records - one `SALE` record, and one `VOID` record.

```
TRX_ID   LINE_ID   STS     ITEM_DESC
-----------------------------------------------------
123456   1         Sale    Sunglasses Mens RS124
123456   2         Void    Sunglasses Mens RS124
123456   3         Sale    Sunglasses NXR RS977
123456   4         Void    Sunglasses NXR RS977
123456   5         Sale    Sunglasses Unisex RS355

123678   1         Sale    Sunglasses Womens RS124w
123678   2         Void    Sunglasses Womens RS124w
123678   3         Sale    Sunglasses Womens RS977w
123678   4         Sale    Sunglasses Womens RS977w
123678   5         Sale    Sunglasses Unisex RS355w
```

I need to write a query to delete records IF the following item within the transaction has been voided (STS='VOID'), only retain the 'net' transactions.

I'm using `LEAD` to have the query examine the following record, I just don't know how to combine the `DELETE FROM` and `LEAD` together. I've unsuccessfully tried using this query:

```
DELETE FROM SALES 
WHERE xxx IN (SELECT 
                  TRX_ID, LINE_ID, LEAD (T1.STS, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY T1.TRX_ID ORDER BY T1.LINE_ID)  NEXT_STS
              FROM SALES_TRANSACTIONS T1) 
WHERE NEXT_STS = 'V'
```

Except outcome: the following records are deleted:

```
TRX_ID   LINE_ID   STS     ITEM_DESC
----------------------------------------------------
123456   1         Sale    Sunglasses Mens RS124
123456   2         Void    Sunglasses Mens RS124
123456   3         Sale    Sunglasses NXR RS977
123456   4         Void    Sunglasses NXR RS977
123678   1         Sale    Sunglasses Womens RS124w
123678   2         Void    Sunglasses Womens RS124w
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in several ways. One is to use `lead` in a common table expression, and then delete from that:

```
with extra as (
    select sts,
           lead(sts) over (partition by trx_id order by line_id) leadsts
    from   sales
)
delete 
from   extra
where  'Void' in (sts, leadsts);
```